# Reusable Liferay (6.0.6) service

Tags: liferay-6

I am trying to implement resuable Custom Services without using ext and servicebuilder. 
I referred this article: http://www.devatwork.nl/2010/04/implementing-a-reusable-liferay-service-without-ext-or-service-builder/ , but I am confused in how should I implement this using eclipse? Following are the steps that I followed to do this:

```
- Created liferay-plugin project within eclipse.
- Created package containing CustomServices (interface) and CustomServicesUtil.
- Created jar file of package in step 2.
- Placed that jar file in tomcat\lib\ext\
- Then created package (with in same liferay-plugin project), that includes CutomServicesImpl and CustomServicesBaseImpl
- Defined portlet-spring.xml, service.properties, and modified web.xml (as per the article), and finally deployed the project.
```

On deployment, project is deployed successfully, but when I am trying to use customMethods defined in CustomServicesImpl through CustomServicesUtil.getCustomMethod(), I am getting the following error:

```
        "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.custom.services.CustomServicesUtil"
```

I configure build path to include customservices.jar file but its not working out, still showing the same error. I don’t know whether this is the correct way to implement resuable services or not. I tried this so that i can make use of  custom method in one of my project.

Here is the code for custom services:

- CustomServices.java

  ```
   package com.demo.custom.services;

   import com.liferay.portal.model.User;

   public interface CustomServices {
      String getCustomName(User user);
   }
  ```
- CustomServicesUtil.java

  ```
      package com.demo.custom.services;

      import com.liferay.portal.model.User;

      public class CustomServicesUtil {
          private static CustomServices services;

          public static CustomServices getServices() {
              if (services == null) {
                  throw new RuntimeException("Custom Services not set");
              }

              return services;
          }

          public void setServices(CustomServices pServices) {
              services = pServices;
          }

          public static String getCustomName(User user){
              return getServices().getCustomName(user);
          }
      }
  ```
- CustomServicesBaseImpl.java

  ```
  package com.demo.custom.services.impl;

  import com.demo.custom.services.CustomServices;
  import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
  import com.liferay.portal.service.base.PrincipalBean;
  import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;

  public abstract class CustomServicesBaseImpl extends PrincipalBean implements CustomServices {
      protected CustomServices services;

      public CustomServices getServices() {
          return services;
      }

      public void setServices(CustomServices pServices) {
          this.services = pServices;
      }
      protected void runSQL(String sql) throws SystemException {
          try {
              PortalUtil.runSQL(sql);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new SystemException(e);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- CustomServicesImpl.java

  ```
  package com.demo.custom.services.impl;

  import com.liferay.portal.model.User;

  public class CustomServicesImpl extends CustomServicesBaseImpl {

      @Override
      public String getCustomName(User user) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          if(user == null){
              return null;
          }else{
              return new StringBuffer().append(user.getFirstName()).append(" ").append(user.getLastName()).toString();
          }
      }

  }
  ```

Here is the code of controller class of my another portlet, where i am making use of this service.

- HelloCustomName.java

  ```
  package com.test;

  import java.io.IOException;

  import javax.portlet.PortletException;
  import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
  import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

  import com.demo.custom.services.CustomServicesUtil;
  import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;
  import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
  import com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay;
  import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;


  public class HelloCustomName extends MVCPortlet {

      @Override
      public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest,
              RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
          System.out.println("--doview----");
          ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
          User user = themeDisplay.getUser();
          String customName = CustomServicesUtil.getCustomName(user); //getting error here
          System.out.println("customName:" + customName);
          }
  }
  ```

Please point me on how to implement resuable services? Any guidance will be really useful.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Have you try to start liferay outside of eclipse? ClassNotFoundException says, that this class cann't be found by classloader.

Comment: 2. Do you want create many projects that access this services or why is it requireble to make resuable services?

Comment: @2 Yes, I want to minimize the use of ext and want to create a reusable component which can be useful in other projects. I am new in liferay and didn't have much idea about this, but the only way i found against not to use ext is reusable component.

Comment: @1 As mentioned, I configured the build path with necessary jar file, still it gives me classNotFoundException, so i am still figuring the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

My mind, you don't need the complexity of services. Simply make utility classes and put this in to `tomcat/lib/ext`. Be sure that `tomcat/lib/ext` is correct configured in `tomcat/conf/catalina.properties`, something like this:

```
  common.loader=${catalina.home}/lib/ext/*.jar
```